# Custom ScrollView, How to make NSView setFrame: faster?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, scroll, nsview

I am making my own ScrollView. 
here is the code i use for scrolling with mouse wheel or touchpad
but it doesn't work flawless. it lags a bit.

```
- (void) scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSRect rect = [contentView frame];
    rect.origin.x += [theEvent deltaX];
    rect.origin.y += [theEvent deltaY];

    [contentView setFrame:rect];
}
```

when i do the same with layers (for test) it works much better.

```
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
[CATransaction begin];
[contentView layer].frame = newRect;
[CATransaction commit];
```

how to make setFrame work flawless?

Comment: You could try using `-setFrameOrigin:` instead of `-setFrame:` since you’re changing the frame origin only.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking hard, on how it is done by apple in NSScrollView. and the answer is that they make high performance drawing - only the changed parts, not the whole view as it is usually done.

After that i decided to customize the standard scrollView and standard scrollers.